# wxpython `GetScrollPos` with ULC not working

Tags: python, wxpython

Hi I have this code :

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl as ULC

class UltimateListCtrl(ULC.UltimateListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, agwStyle=0):

        ULC.UltimateListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, agwStyle=agwStyle)

        self.Bind( wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.onClick)
        
    def onClick(self,event):
        print (self.GetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL))
        event.Skip()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):

        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 321))
        self.SetTitle("frame")

        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        

        self.list_ctrl_1 = UltimateListCtrl(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY,agwStyle=ULC.ULC_REPORT | ULC.ULC_VRULES  )
        self.list_ctrl_1.InsertColumn(0, "A", format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width=-1)
        self.list_ctrl_1.InsertColumn(1, "B", format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width=-1)
        self.list_ctrl_1.InsertColumn(2, "C", format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width=-1)
        sizer_1.Add(self.list_ctrl_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        
        
        index = self.list_ctrl_1.InsertStringItem(0, "1")  
        self.list_ctrl_1.SetStringItem(index, 1,"2")
        self.list_ctrl_1.SetStringItem(index, 2,"3")

        index = self.list_ctrl_1.InsertStringItem(1, "1")  
        self.list_ctrl_1.SetStringItem(index, 1,"2")
        self.list_ctrl_1.SetStringItem(index, 2,"3")
        
        
        self.panel_1.SetSizer(sizer_1)

        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade



class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I Duple Click on an item in ULC(UltimateListCtrl) it must print `ScrollPos` but I have this error instead :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Ult.py", line 29, in onClick
    print 'self.GetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL)' , self.GetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL)
TypeError: GetScrollPos() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

But I am giving `GetScrollPos()` just 1  argument  not 2 arguments `self.GetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL)`!
What is my mistake here ?

Edit :

I found this Note in UltimateListCtrl Doc :

GetScrollPos(self, orientation)

```
Returns the scrollbar position.

Note

`This method is forwarded to UltimateListMainWindow.`

Parameters

    orientation – May be wx.HORIZONTAL or wx.VERTICAL.
```

Is the forwarding to UltimateListMainWindow cause this error ?
If yes then how to fix this error ?

Comment: The "self" is an implicit hidden argument of object methods therefore you should give no argument.

Comment: if I give no argument `self.GetScrollPos()` I get this error `TypeError: Required argument 'orientation' (pos 2) not found`

Comment: Show the full tracebacks of the errors as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: you can see full tracebacks of the errors in my question now

Comment: In the comments you mentioned another error after changing the code. What is the traceback of this error? Which version of wxPython are you using?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Ult.py", line 29, in onClick
    print  self.GetScrollPos()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\lib\agw\ultimatelistctrl.py", line 13378, in GetScrollPos
    return self._mainWin.GetScrollPos()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_core.py", line 10328, in GetScrollPos
    return _core_.Window_GetScrollPos(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: Required argument 'orientation' (pos 2) not found` wxPython version is wx-2.8

Comment: It sounds like you are reading the documentation for the latest version but using a defunct version of the code and expecting them to agree. Try printing something useful like `print(event.GetLabel())` or better still, load a version that is up to date.